# Inconsistent Address and mask

Tags: routing, router, ipv4, ip, subnet

When statically routing a route in the format [destination network address] [mask] [next hop address or interface name], I get the Inconsistent Address and mask error. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Network address:`10.10.233.0`
Mask: `255.255.254.0` (fitted to suit 300 host )
Hop address: `10.10.235.162`

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

That would be correct. If you mask the address you think is the network's address with the network mask, you get a different, real network address.

```
Address   10.10.233.0 = 00001010000010101110100100000000
Mask    255.255.254.0 = 11111111111111111111111000000000
                 AND    ================================
Network                 00001010000010101110100000000000 = 10.10.232.0
```

The network is from `10.10.232.0` to `10.10.233.255.255`.

You must do IP math in binary, then it makes sense, and otherwise you make mistakes. See this [excellent answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/7117/8499) for how to do that.

With that mask (`255.255.254.0`), that address (`10.10.233.0`) is not a network address, it is a host address on a different network (`10.10.232.0`).

Comment: so if i was to continue using the network 10.10.233.0 what changes will i have to make?

Comment: With that mask, that is not a network address, it is a host address on a different network.

Comment: so i might as well begin redoing my entire sub netting table and routing configurations then.

Comment: You really, really need to do it in binary. It is a rookie move not to, and it leads to stupid mistakes like this one.

Comment: 10.10.232.0/23 includes both 10.10.232.0/24 and 10.10.233.0/24.  If you just want to route to the latter then change the mask on your statement to 255.255.255.0.  If you want a subnet that can accept 300 hosts then keep the mask the same and change the network to 10.10.232.0.  Either way read Ron's answer (and the pointer he provided) again to help you better understand subnetting and how to correctly build your address plan.